# Do pokemon that don't kill still get EVs?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I have completed sapphire and I am still playing because my friends and I trade and battle. I am using MyBoy on android to play. I have a question, to which I haven't found a solution online yet.

I have Swablu(Macho brace) and Rayquaza(Mental herb). My swablu is quite weak so I put it as my first Pokémon and then switch out when the battle starts to gain exp.

I know you only get **EVs** by battling, but will my EVs be doubled if **RayQ kills the wild Pokemon** ?

Comment: If you have three different questions, please ask three seperate questions instead of putting them into one

Comment: ^ ask three different questions*

Comment: @n_palum Can't undo now

Comment: May I suggest doing some research before asking? Ruby and Sapphire are very old, and have been covered extensively.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yep I did but not found the answer .

Comment: @ShubhamWagh I was teasingly correcting the first guy - and you can undo, you can also edit, and delete.

Comment: @n_palum Edited you may answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Pokemon that gains EXP from battle (either through holding Exp.Share, or being switched out) will gain [Effort Value points](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values#Modern_system) for defeating that Pokemon, regardless of their actual contribution to the defeat of the enemy Pokemon.

For your Swablu (+macho brace) example: If you were fighting a wild Golbat for +2speed, and switched your leading Swablu out for Rayquaza, your Swablu would still get 4 points of speed EVs (8 if it also had Pokerus).